# What is the worst that can happen if one does not file for bankruptcy but cannot pay their debt either (in Canada)?

Tags: canada, debt, bankruptcy, expiration

In a situation when one does not file for bankruptcy, yet does not pay their debts, collectors start calling and mailing, then the creditors may file a lawsuit. But if one doesn't have any property or wages to garnish, what can happen and how long will it last? Is there any expiry date on unpaid debts in Canada?

Comment: Bankruptcy may be forced by debtors

Comment: @littleadv Do you mean forced by creditors? Would this result in something like a default bankruptcy?

Comment: yes, creditors, sorry. I don't know the technical term, but it would restrict your financial freedom significantly.

Comment: AFAIK bankruptcy does not restrict financial freedom, it only severely limits the ability to borrow.

Comment: Depending on the Canadian laws, of course, it does very much do so. You'll need to report all your income, all your expenses, and the court may allocate some of your income to your debtors and forbid you from spending excessive income above what's necessary.